# How to change font properties of a matplotlib colorbar label?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, I want to change the font properties for a `colorbar` label. For example I want the label to appear bold.

Here is some example code:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
pcolor(arange(20).reshape(4,5))
cb = colorbar(label='a label')
```

and the result, where I want *"a label"* to appear bold:

[image: output plot]

All other answers on this site only answer how to change `ticklabels` or change all fonts in general (via modification of the `matplotlibrc` file)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This two-liner can be used with any Text property (http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

```
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label(label='a label',weight='bold')
```

Answer (score 22):

I agree with francesco, but even shorten to one line:

```
plt.colorbar().set_label(label='a label',size=15,weight='bold')
```

Answer (score 18):

As an alternative to unutbu's answer you could take advantage of the fact that a color bar is another axes instance in the figure and set the label font like you would set any y-label.

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from numpy import arange

pcolor(arange(20).reshape(4,5))
cb = colorbar(label='a label')
ax = cb.ax
text = ax.yaxis.label
font = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(family='times new roman', style='italic', size=16)
text.set_font_properties(font)
show()
```

[image: figure with colorbar]

Comment: @thengineer: Use `family='times new roman', weight='bold', style='normal'` to get a bold label.

Comment: thanks! I didnt know the colorbar is just an axes and the label just an ylabel.

Answer (score 4):

To change the font size of your colorbar's tick and label:

```
clb=plt.colorbar()
clb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8) 
clb.ax.set_title('Your Label',fontsize=8)
```

This can be also used if you have sublots:

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05)
cax = plt.axes([0.1, 0, 0.8, 0.01]) #Left,bottom, length, width
clb=plt.colorbar(cax=cax,orientation='horizontal')
clb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8) 
clb.ax.set_title('Your Label',fontsize=8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use TeX: `r'\textbf{a label}'`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.pcolor(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5))
cb = plt.colorbar(label=r'\textbf{a label}')
plt.show()
```

[image]