# matplotlib label formatting font changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, text, string-formatting

I use `matplotlib` to generate data analysis plots, which I then show to people at conferences, in publications etc. I normally store all the data and scripts that generate every interesting/useful plot, just in case I need to update the charts at some point after creating them. Here's an example of my box-standard piece of code that generates the below plot:

```
# In[Imports]:
import pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot

# In[Plot formatting]:
ticksFontSize = 18
labelsFontSize = 30
legendFontSize = 16
cm=matplotlib.pyplot.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=ticksFontSize)
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=ticksFontSize)

# In[Read the data]:
# CDF of TLE update frequenies
dfGood=pandas.read_csv('blue.csv',sep=',',header=None)
epochsGood=dfGood[0].values
cdfsGood=dfGood[1].values

# In[Plot the data]:
fig,ax=matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(1,1,sharex=True,figsize=(14,8))
ax.scatter(epochsGood,cdfsGood,c='indigo',marker='o',lw=0,s=30)
ax.set_xlabel(r"$TLE\ update\ frequency\ (orbital\ periods)$",
    size=labelsFontSize)
ax.set_ylabel(r"$Cumulative\ Distribution\ Function\ (-)$",
    fontsize=labelsFontSize)
ax.grid(linewidth=1)    
ax.tick_params(axis='both',reset=False,which='both',
    length=5,width=1.5)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)
ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.1)
matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right=0.95,
    bottom=0.15,top=0.9)
fig.show()
```

[image: Old matplotlib]

Recently (within the last few months, but it could have been a long overdue update...), I updated `matplotlib` and the above script started generating a differently formatted plot:

[image: New matplotlib]

The clipped Y-axis is no biggie, I can just live with that and adjust the plot/axis. What I am a bit perplexed about is the changed font. It appears that sometime during the `matplotlib` update the `matplotlibrc` file has changed. I can live with that and explicitly set `matplotlibrc` properties in my scripts, or set label text properties on a per-label basis as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172282/how-to-change-font-properties-of-a-matplotlib-colorbar-label). But I have no idea how to go back to the *previous formatting*, i.e. what text properties to set. Any ideas?

## Some useful info

1. Current Python version = 3.5.4
2. Python version I used to generate the *"old plot"* = 3.5.something
3. Current `matplotlib` version = 2.2.2
4. `matplotlib` version I used to generate the *"old plot"* = I wish I knew...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default math font has changed in version 2.x [from "Computer Modern" to "DejaVu Sans"](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#math-text). You can change it in your script as mentioned in the documentation back to the previous version:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = 'serif'
```

Sample output (without your data because your question does not contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):
[image]