# Can I plot a colorbar from a list of colors and for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

Here's part of the Python code I'm working on:

```
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('defcol', ["#000000", "#FF0000"])
trace_color = cm(np.linspace(0,1,cycles))
for k, color in zip(range(cycles),trace_color):
        lis = KL_rest[k::cycles]
        plt.scatter(scanpoints, lis, color = color, marker = '^', alpha = 0.9)
```

Here I am generating the scatter plot using a for loop, and the colors come from the list `trace_color`. My question is if I can generate a colorbar, where the colors are from the `trace_color` and labels (scale) on the colorbar come from `range(cycles)`. I tried to add `plt.colorbar()` after the for loop but that didn't work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib's colorbar needs a `ScalarMappable` object.  By default, it is taken from what's plotted, e.g. a scatter plot that is created in one call. If you need to combine the results of multiple calls, you can create an own `ScalarMappable`. It needs a colormap and [a norm](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

cycles = 7
N = 100
KL_rest = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, cycles * N))
scanpoints = np.arange(N)
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('defcol', ["#000000", "#FF0000"])
trace_color = cm(np.linspace(0, 1, cycles))
for k, color in zip(range(cycles), trace_color):
    lis = KL_rest[k::cycles]
    plt.scatter(scanpoints, lis, color=color, marker='^', alpha=0.9)
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cm, norm=plt.Normalize(0, cycles - 1)), ticks=np.arange(cycles), label='cycles')
plt.show()
```

[image: custom colorbar]

Note that in this case, you can create the scatter plot in one go, enabling a default color bar. For this to work, the `scanpoints` can be repeated for each cycle, and the colors can be indicated by tiling the cycle for each scan point.

If you only want to show the really used colors, you can add `N=cycles` in the creation of the color map. To put the tick marks for each number in the center of the cells, you can move the default limits by `0.5`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

cycles = 7
N = 100
KL_rest = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, cycles * N))
scanpoints = np.arange(N)
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('defcol', ["#000000", "#FF0000"], N=cycles)

plt.scatter(np.repeat(scanpoints, cycles), KL_rest,
            c=np.tile(range(cycles), len(scanpoints)),
            cmap=cm, norm=plt.Normalize(-0.5, cycles - 0.5),
            marker='^', alpha=0.9)
plt.colorbar(ticks=np.arange(cycles), label='cycles')
plt.show()
```

[image: scatterplot in one go]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Is there a way I can change the font size of the colorbar?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172282/how-to-change-font-properties-of-a-matplotlib-colorbar-label or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233108/seaborn-change-font-size-of-the-colorbar